# Можно ли сделать такое в grid?

Tags: html, css

Имеется код:

```
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  overflow-x: scroll;
```

Нужен для свайпа элементов на мобильном устройстве, при помощи пальца.
Есть ли возможность сделать такое на grid?
Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

```
  overflow-x: scroll;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(14, 180px);
```

Такой метод подошел, правда приходится задавать строго сколько элементов будет. Не нашел, как сделать "auto"